# How to check if Gatsby site has launched as a PWA before layout renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

In `gatsby-browser` and `gatsby-ssr` I have attached a global context provider via `wrapRootElement` which provides a state of whether the site has been launched as a PWA or not.

This state is used in my `Layout` component to conditionally render an app tab bar at the bottom of the screen for the PWA or a nav bar at the top of the screen otherwise. I'm using `wrapPageElement` in `gatsby-browser` to mount `Layout` to all pages.

```
//interfaceContext.js

export const InterfaceContext = React.createContext()

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [appInterface, setAppInterface] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
      if (
        !(
          navigator.standalone ||
          window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches
        )
      ) {
        setAppInterface(false)
      }
  }, [])

export default ({ element }) => <Provider>{element}</Provider>
```

```
//gatsby-ssr.js & gatsby-browser.js

export const wrapRootElement = Provider

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => <Layout>{element}</Layout>
```

```
//layout.js

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const context = useContext(InterfaceContext)
  return (
    <>
      {context.appInterface ? <AppBar /> : <DesktopNav />}
      ...
```

At the moment this works but I think the default state is being used during server side rendering at build and on initial load or reload my site flashes the default nav position before my context provider updates it. How can I update this state before the layout renders to screen to prevent the flash?